# how to implement function from another .js file in Titanium

Tags: titanium

how to use functions/methods from another .js file in titanium?

eg
Utils.js

```
var db = Titanium.Database.open('myinfodb');
function addIntoDb(name) {
    db.execute('INSERT INTO info (name) VALUES(?)', name);
    Ti.Ti.API.info(name+' Added to db');
}

function getFromDb() {
    var holddatavar = db.execute('SELECT name FROM info');
    return holddatavar;
}

db.close();
```

how to use this in my current js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

db.js

```
// creates your database if necessary
var db = Titanium.Database.open('myinfodb');
db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [info] (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT)');
db.close();

var addIntoDb = function(name) {
    var db = Titanium.Database.open('myinfodb');
    db.execute('INSERT INTO info (name) VALUES(?)', name);
    Ti.Ti.API.info(name+' Added to db');
    db.close();
}
exports.addIntoDb = addIntoDb; // <=== This exposes the function to another file

// This function would remain accessible only to the file because we didn't export the function
function getFromDb() {
    var holddatavar = db.execute('SELECT name FROM info');
    return holddatavar;
}
```

Then you would use it in other JavaScript files to access it like so:

```
var db = require('/mypath/db'); // NO .js extension on this
db.addIntoDb('Pravin');
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it.
just

```
Ti.include('/ui/common/Utils.js');
```

and

Utils.js will be

```
addStudent= function addIntoDb(name) {
    var db = Titanium.Database.open('myinfodb');
    db.execute('INSERT INTO info (name) VALUES(?)', name);
    Ti.API.info(name+' Added to db');
}

getStudent=function getFromDb() {
    var db = Titanium.Database.open('myinfodb');
    var holddatavar = db.execute('SELECT name FROM info');
    return holddatavar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using commonJS then you can do it simply including that file i mean create one file for such function and include that file in your current.js file and call that function.

Answer (score 0):

var All = require('ui/common/All');

```
    Tree = require('ui/common/Tree');

    EBOM = require('ui/common/E-BOM');

    MBOM = require('ui/common/M-BOM');

    SBOM = require('ui/common/S-BOM');

//create object instance

var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({

    title:'Products',

    exitOnClose:true,

    navBarHidden:true,

    backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    activity: {

        onCreateOptionsMenu: function(e) {

            var menu = e.menu;         

            var menuItem = menu.add({ title: "C-BOM", icon: 'Arrow-Hover.jpg' });

            //menuItem.setIcon("Arrow-Hover.jpg");

            menuItem.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

                 var all = new All();

                        self.add(all);

            });

            (.....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Best is to make subfolder in /lib folder like /Utils and put there a file in /Utils/Utils.js.

Then in index.js controller add global variable like :

> Alloy.Globals.Helpers=Ti.include('/Utils/Utils.js')

When you do it like this your file is now accessible in any controller you make.
Note this is for Alloy but it is almost the same for classic Titanium.